# Undefined property PHP error on Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am super stuck on a problem. I went through many solution give here related to this but I did not found any solution to my error.

this is the error message I am facing and I used print_r to view what is the output but is also a dead end.

[image]

My controller - **Search.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {

    function index(){
        $this->load->model("ModSearch");
        $data["get_ztable"] = $this->ModSearch->get_zscore();       
        $data["get_course"] = $this->ModSearch->getCourse();
        $data["get_stream"] = $this->ModSearch->getStream();    
        $data["get_district"] = $this->ModSearch->getDistrict();
        $data["get_uni"] = $this->ModSearch->getUniversity();       
        $this->load->view('addZscore',$data);

    }
```

Model - **ModSearch.php**

```
public function get_zscore(){       
        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_zscore');
        return $query;
    }
```

View - **addZscore.php**

```
<table style="width:50%">
   <tr>
      <th>Z ID</th>
      <th>Z Score</th>
   </tr>
   <?php echo print_r($get_ztable);?>
   <?php
      if($get_ztable->num_rows() > 0)
      {
      foreach ($get_ztable as $row)
      {
      ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row->z_id; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->z_score; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      }
       }else{
      echo 'Database Error(' . $this->db->_error_number() . ') - ' . $this->db->_error_message();
       }
       ?>
</table>
```

Comment: `$row` is not what you think it is, It's not a result row, its your Mysqli instance, so trying to access `z_id` a property which does not exist in class Mysqli, gives you the error.  At least that is what that error message means.  You need to `fetch` the data instead of iterating with foreach.

Comment: `while ($row = $get_ztable->fetch_object())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make changes in your model function that must return a "result" that you can easily use in your view. So just replace

```
return $query
```

with

```
return $query->result()
```

Or make a change in your foreach loop in views from

```
foreach($get_ztable as $row)
```

to

```
foreach($get_ztable->result() as $row)
```